# Allow in flight requests to complete before tomcat/spring mvc container shutdown

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, shutdown, application-shutdown

Spring 4.2.3
Spring Mvc Web Application running on tomcat 7.

When shutting down tomcat, I am looking for a way to perform the following.

- Stop receiving any **new** requests
- Allow all current **in flight** http requests to complete, before spring/tomcat starts shutting down all the services etc..

The reason for this, I have an application that deals with customers purchasing pre paid products. (Airtime, electricity etc..). All requests that that have entered my application, must be allowed to complete before the shutdown to ensure the integrity of my data and the transaction itself.

I know I can use `@PreDestroy` on my spring beans as a hook to perform actions on the shutdown. But I require an application wide approach that will give me hook before spring or the container even begins to shut down my services.

I have been re searching for a few hours now and I have been unable to find what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot 1.5+ provides an option to do the graceful shutdown of an application which helps to complete the processing of in flight requests before application shutdown.

**Flow of an Graceful shutdown of SpringBoot app** :

1. The JVM receives the SIGTERM signal and starts shutting down the Spring container.
2. A Spring EventListener listens for a ContextClosedEvent and is invoked once the shutdown is started.
3. The EventListener updates a Spring Boot HealthIndicator and puts it "out of service".
4. The context shutdown is delayed using a Thread.sleep to allow the load balancer to see the updated HealthIndicator status and stop forwarding requests to this instance.
5. When the Thread.sleep is finished, the Tomcat container is gracefully shutdown. First by pausing the connector, no longer accepting new request. Next, by allowing the Tomcat thread pool a configurable amount of time to finish the active threads.
6. Finally, the Spring context is closed.

Helpful links :

https://github.com/timpeeters/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown
https://github.com/SchweizerischeBundesbahnen/springboot-graceful-shutdown
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown